# Hibernate Criteria by Examle

Tags: hibernate, criteria, query-by-example

I am trying to create Criteria by an Example. But I am getting the same results for the different Example objects.

```
Author author = new Author();
author.setId(3L);
News news = new News();
news.setAuthor(author);

List<News> newsList = getSession().createCriteria(News.class)
           .add(Example.create(news))
           .list();
```

If I change the id, then I get the the same news list.
I tried to do next:

```
//...
.add(Example.create(news.getAuthor())
```

But it doesn't work too. I know that I can use for example Restrictions or HQL, but I would like to try do it like that.
How to use the Examle correctly?

Comment: Did you try to get the author with `session.get<Author>(3L)` instead of creating a new one?

Comment: @StefanSteinegger No, I didn't. I prefer to do a less database queries.

Comment: So create a proxy ... (`session.load()` I think).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#criteria-examples)

> Version properties, identifiers and associations are ignored. By default, null valued properties are excluded.